# Spring-Boot CrudRepository not found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to get a CrudRepository to work:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.codynx.itemizer.model.Task;

@Repository
public interface TaskMysqlRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Integer> {

}
```

used here:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.codynx.itemizer.model.Task;
import com.codynx.itemizer.repository.TaskMysqlRepository;

@Service
public class TaskMysqlService {
    public ResultSet resultSet = null;
    private Iterable<Task> tasks;
    
    @Autowired
    private TaskMysqlRepository taskMysqlRepository;
    
    public TaskMysqlService() {
        
    }
    
    public Iterable<Task> getTasks(){
        return taskMysqlRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

But I get the error message:

required a bean of type 'com.codynx.itemizer.repository.TaskMysqlRepository' that could not be found

The repo is there and has the correct annotation. What am I doing wrong?

Here is also the Task Type:

[...]

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Task {
    
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    @Version
    private Long version;
    
    private LocalDateTime start;
    
    private LocalDateTime due;
    
    private boolean done;
    
    private String name;
    
    private Integer parent_id;

}
```

Is it because of some type missmatch? I mean the repo is there...

Answer (score 1):

May be in your case due to package structure, autoconfiguration is not happening.
Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` and mention the packages.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.entities.package"}) //your entities package goes here
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.repositories.package"})//your repository package goes here
public class SpringBootDataJpaApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDataJpaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think thats the right track, I have seen something like @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { ItemApplication.BASE_PACKAGE }) in another file (there is also a Mongo DB inside and I want to use a mysql DB too), but the Mongo base packe is the App root, hm not sure how to fix this yet

Comment: Well you can provide multiple packages to be scanned and autoconfigured.
Something like

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.repo.package1","com.repo.package2" })

Comment: All have the same "aolution", and it doesn't work